# SSRS Calculations with multiple datasets using clng function

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report with 3 datasets. Each dataset is pulling data from a different data warehouse but all pulling the same data. At the end of my report, I have a table that is getting the totals from each dataset, and I have successfully done this for normal total fields. However, there are some fields that are percentages. Below is an example of the expression I have in my text box.

I am taking the existing expression from the table with one dataset and trying to add the value from each data set so I can get a total percentage.

**Field using 1 dataset**

```
=Code.SafeDivideVariance(Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value)), 
Sum(CLng(Fields!LY_Sales_Retail.Value)))
```

**Field combining all data sets**

```
=Code.SafeDivideVariance(
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value, "Dataset1")) +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value, "Dataset2")) +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value, "Dataset3")) +
, 
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value, "Dataset1")) +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value, "Dataset2")) +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value, "Dataset3"))
)
```

However, when I try this I get the following error.
"The value expression for the textrun contains an error: [BC30198] ) expected.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/895CF.png)

**UPDATE** I have added two fields one with the code

```
=Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset1") + 
Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset2") +  
Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset3")
```

and the other with

```
=Sum(CLng(Fields!LY_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset1") + 
Sum(CLng(Fields!LY_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset2") + 
Sum(CLng(Fields!LY_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset3")
```

I am getting the following error

> The value expression for the text box 'Textbox11' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

I get the same error even if I just try

```
=Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset2")
```

**UPDATE 2.0**

Here is the report design, dataset 2 and 3 are the same as dataset1 but they look at the respective data sources.

[Report design 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbeqH.png)

[Report design 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RotLo.png)

[Report Design 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJqt8.png)

The first 3 tables are looking at an individual data source. The last table is looking as dataset1 but I am summing the totals of all 3 in each field.

[Report Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPdqx.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your report design and include the report data panel showing datsets and field names, and also the grouping panel showing row and column groups (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset was typed incorrectly and not matching my actual dataset name. The S in set needed to be a capital.

```
=Code.SafeDivideVariance(
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value), "DataSet1") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value), "DataSet2") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value), "DataSet3") +
, 
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value), "DataSet1") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value), "DataSet2") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value), "DataSet3")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now but try the following

```
=Code.SafeDivideVariance(
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value), "Dataset1") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value), "Dataset2") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value), "Dataset3") +
, 
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value), "Dataset1") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value), "Dataset2") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value), "Dataset3")
)
```

It's the out aggregate function (`SUM` in your case) that needs the scope specifying I think. Your original code had the scope as part of the `CLng` function

**Update**
I can't actually see anything wrong. I've tested with some sample data and it works as expected.

I suggest you add 2 textboxes to show the results of each value that you are passing to your custom function. It may be that there is an issue there. e.g. the first textbox would have the vaule expression set to

```
=Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset1") + Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset2") +  Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset3")
```

Make sure that the values you see here are what you expect.

If this does not work then please EDIT your question and show some sample data so I can reproduce the issue. As it stands, it is working as expected.

Comment: when I try that I get the following error

**"The value expression for the text box has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset."**

Comment: you'll need to post the safedevidevariance code, then I'll take look tomorrow (it's almost midnight here)

Comment: Here is the code, Its only morning here =)

`=Code.SafeDivideVariance(
Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset1") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset2") + 
Sum(CLng(Fields!TP_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset3")
, 
Sum(CLng(Fields!LY_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset1") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!LY_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset2") +
Sum(CLng(Fields!LY_Sales_Retail.Value), "Dataset3")
)`

Comment: I need to see the custom code for the SafeDivideVariance function you are using, not the expression that you use it in.

Comment: sorry I am new to this here it is.   
   
`Public Function SafeDivideVariance(Numerator as String, Denominator as String) as String  
Try  
If Numerator = "" or Denominator = "" then
 Return "-"
End if  
If Numerator = "-" or Denominator = "-" then  
 Return "-"
End If
If CDbl(Numerator) =0 or CDbl(Denominator) = 0 then
 Return "-"
End if
If (IsNothing(Numerator)) Or  (IsNothing(Denominator)) Then  
 Return "-"  
End If  

Return String.format(((Numerator/ Denominator )-1).ToString("0.0%"))

Catch ex as exception  
 Return ex.message  
End Try  
End Function`

Comment: I've added some more info in my answer. If you need to update your question, click the edit link rather than posting info in the comments.